# AngularJs Create Table using ng-repeat from custom Json

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to create html table. I use AngularJs directive - ng-repeat. I have data which is loaded from server. Data type is text/json.  My Json structure is below

```
[  
   {  
      "branch":"wdads",
      "name":"STANDART",
      "Tags":[  

      ],
      "Rooms":[  
         {  
            "roomNo":"11",
            "branch":"wdads",
            "Schedule":[  
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-10-31T20:00:00.000Z"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-10-31T20:00:00.000Z"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "branch":"wdads",
      "name":"VIP",
      "Tags":[  

      ],
      "Rooms":[  
         {  
            "roomNo":"1",
            "branch":"wdads",
            "Schedule":[  
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-12-29T20:00:00.000Z"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-12-29T20:00:00.000Z"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "roomNo":"2",
            "branch":"wdads",
            "Schedule":[  
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-12-29T20:00:00.000Z"
               },
               {  
                  "id":"",
                  "status":"free",
                  "currentDate":"2015-12-29T20:00:00.000Z"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I'm trying to create table body, but it does not working. I don't have result.

```
 <tbody>
            <div ng-repeat="caterory in categories">
              <tr>{{caterory.name}}<tr>
              <tr ng-repeat="room in caterory.Rooms">
                <td>{{room.roomNo}}</td>
                <td ng-repeat="schedule in room.Schedule">{{schedule.status}}</td>
              </tr>
            </div>
          </tbody>
```

Comment: What is the problem with current implementation?

Comment: I don't have result, in result i mean view side.

Comment: did you tried what I suggested in my below answer?

Comment: No sorry, i don't understand your suggestion. Can you explain again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the html you wrote is invalid html.

You could not have `div` element directly inside `table`'s `tbody`, `thead`, `tfoot`, `tr` elements, If you tried to do this then that HTML would be considered as an invalid html.

You could have that element inside `th`/`td` element of the table. Basically this elements are used to display data on table.

To solving you problem you need to do couple of things.

1. You should place the `ng-repeat` on `tbody`, and repeating `tbody` of table multiple times.
2. While showing data on table row from `tr` tag you should use `td` element. As you are directly using `tr` should be changed to `<tr><td ng-bind="$first ?caterory.name : ''"></td><tr>`

**Markup**

```
<tbody ng-repeat="caterory in categories">
    <tr ng-repeat="room in caterory.Rooms">
      <td ng-bind="$first ?caterory.name : ''"></td>
      <td>{{room.roomNo}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="schedule in room.Schedule">{{schedule.status}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

More detailed answer here [**How to structure html while using table**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33551496/2435473).

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/96aqGWGo70OfvtGaZGQf?p=preview)

Comment: when i try to use this code i have different table body. I don't have <tr>{{caterory.name}}</tr> this row in table

Comment: can you help me how to fix this problem ?

Comment: @zuri Yes I've fixed you problem..do look at updated code an answer..I'm updating the explanation right away..

Comment: this code works good for me, <tr>
              <td>{{ caterory.name }}</td> 
            </tr>

Comment: is it possible to do that ng-click="{{ schedule.action }}". i need to call different function. when i write this i got the following error Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{ schedule.action }}] starting at [{ schedule.action }}].

Comment: basically you can't have `{{}}` interpolation directive inside `ng-click` directive

Answer (score 1):

Do something

```
<tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="caterory in categories">{{caterory.name}}<tr>
     <tr ng-repeat="room in caterory.Rooms">
        <td>{{room.roomNo}}</td>
        <td ng-repeat="schedule in room.Schedule">{{schedule.status}}</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Result is same, table body could not created with this code