# Angular js validations for a form in ng-repeat is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-validation

I have a table, in which I have repeated the `<tr>` tag by using `ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent"`

Inside this tr tag I have a form with name and id set by using `$index`

Take a look at my code below :

```
<tbody>
    <tr  ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent">
        <form name="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm" id="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm" novalidate>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="{{ $index }}editFromHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.fromHours" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableField" id="{{ $index }}fromHours" required/>
            <p ng-show="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}editFromHours.$touched && {{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}editFromHours.$invalid" class="text-danger">This field is required</p>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="{{ $index }}edittoHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.toHours" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableField" id="{{ $index }}toHours" required/>
            <p ng-show="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}edittoHours.$touched && {{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}edittoHours.$invalid">This field is required</p>
            <p ng-show="{{ $index }}edittoHours>={{ $index }}editFromHours" class="text-danger">To Hours should not be more than to Hours</p>
         </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="{{ $index }}editPer" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.percentage" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableField" id="{{ $index }}percentage" required/>
            <p ng-show="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}editPer.$touched && {{ $index }}editPercentageForm.{{ $index }}editPer.$invalid">This field is required</p>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="disableField = false" ng-show="disableField" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 1%;"  ng-disabled="{{ $index }}editPercentageForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateCancellations(cancellationPercentData, $index+'fromHours', $index+'toHours', $index+'percentage')" ng-show="disableField == false">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="deleteCancellations(cancellationPercentData)" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Delete</button>
        </td>
        </form>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

tr is repeating correctly but the form inside the tr should start immediately after the tr tag and should end exactly before the tr close tag.

But when I open the above code in the browser and inspect, it is showing differently, the form tag is opened and closed without td tags inside it. Once the form is closed then the tg tags are started .

This is how it is getting changes in my browser when I inspect it :

```
<tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent --><tr ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent" class="ng-scope">
        <form name="0editPercentageForm" id="0editPercentageForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></form>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="0editFromHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.fromHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="0fromHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="0editPercentageForm.0editFromHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 0editPercentageForm.0editFromHours.$invalid" class="text-danger">This field is required</p>
        </td><td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="0edittoHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.toHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="0toHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="0editPercentageForm.0edittoHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 0editPercentageForm.0edittoHours.$invalid">This field is required</p>
            <p ng-show="0edittoHours>=0editFromHours" class="text-danger">To Hours should not be more than to Hours</p>
         </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="0editPer" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.percentage" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="0percentage" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="0editPercentageForm.0editPer.$touched &amp;&amp; 0editPercentageForm.0editPer.$invalid">This field is required</p>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="disableField = false" ng-show="disableField" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 ng-hide" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 1%;" ng-disabled="0editPercentageForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateCancellations(cancellationPercentData, $index+'fromHours', $index+'toHours', $index+'percentage')" ng-show="disableField == false">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="deleteCancellations(cancellationPercentData)" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Delete</button>
        </td>

    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent --><tr ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent" class="ng-scope">
        <form name="1editPercentageForm" id="1editPercentageForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></form>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="1editFromHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.fromHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="1fromHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="1editPercentageForm.1editFromHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 1editPercentageForm.1editFromHours.$invalid" class="text-danger">This field is required</p>
        </td><td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="1edittoHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.toHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="1toHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="1editPercentageForm.1edittoHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 1editPercentageForm.1edittoHours.$invalid">This field is required</p>
            <p ng-show="1edittoHours>=1editFromHours" class="text-danger">To Hours should not be more than to Hours</p>
         </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="1editPer" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.percentage" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="1percentage" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="1editPercentageForm.1editPer.$touched &amp;&amp; 1editPercentageForm.1editPer.$invalid">This field is required</p>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="disableField = false" ng-show="disableField" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 ng-hide" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 1%;" ng-disabled="1editPercentageForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateCancellations(cancellationPercentData, $index+'fromHours', $index+'toHours', $index+'percentage')" ng-show="disableField == false">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="deleteCancellations(cancellationPercentData)" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Delete</button>
        </td>

    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent --><tr ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent" class="ng-scope">
        <form name="2editPercentageForm" id="2editPercentageForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></form>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="2editFromHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.fromHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="2fromHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="2editPercentageForm.2editFromHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 2editPercentageForm.2editFromHours.$invalid" class="text-danger">This field is required</p>
        </td><td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="2edittoHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.toHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="2toHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="2editPercentageForm.2edittoHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 2editPercentageForm.2edittoHours.$invalid">This field is required</p>
            <p ng-show="2edittoHours>=2editFromHours" class="text-danger">To Hours should not be more than to Hours</p>
         </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="2editPer" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.percentage" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="2percentage" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="2editPercentageForm.2editPer.$touched &amp;&amp; 2editPercentageForm.2editPer.$invalid">This field is required</p>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="disableField = false" ng-show="disableField" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 ng-hide" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 1%;" ng-disabled="2editPercentageForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateCancellations(cancellationPercentData, $index+'fromHours', $index+'toHours', $index+'percentage')" ng-show="disableField == false">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="deleteCancellations(cancellationPercentData)" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Delete</button>
        </td>

    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent --><tr ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent" class="ng-scope">
        <form name="3editPercentageForm" id="3editPercentageForm" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-valid"></form>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="3editFromHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.fromHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="3fromHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="3editPercentageForm.3editFromHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 3editPercentageForm.3editFromHours.$invalid" class="text-danger">This field is required</p>
        </td><td class="form-group">
            <input type="number" name="3edittoHours" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.toHours" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="3toHours" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="3editPercentageForm.3edittoHours.$touched &amp;&amp; 3editPercentageForm.3edittoHours.$invalid">This field is required</p>
            <p ng-show="3edittoHours>=3editFromHours" class="text-danger">To Hours should not be more than to Hours</p>
         </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="3editPer" ng-model="cancellationPercentData.percentage" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-valid-required" ng-disabled="disableField" id="3percentage" required="" disabled="disabled">
            <p ng-show="3editPercentageForm.3editPer.$touched &amp;&amp; 3editPercentageForm.3editPer.$invalid">This field is required</p>
        </td>
        <td class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="disableField = false" ng-show="disableField" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success col-xs-12 ng-hide" type="submit" style="margin-bottom: 1%;" ng-disabled="3editPercentageForm.$invalid" ng-click="updateCancellations(cancellationPercentData, $index+'fromHours', $index+'toHours', $index+'percentage')" ng-show="disableField == false">Update</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary col-xs-12" type="button" ng-click="deleteCancellations(cancellationPercentData)" style="margin-bottom: 1%;">Delete</button>
        </td>

    </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent -->
    </tbody>
```

Why is getting changed in the browser?

Because of this the validations are not working properly.

Please help, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do you have specific reason by putting repeated form instead of 1 big form surrounding the whole table?

Comment: As I am using ng-repeat I thought the form should also be repeated along with the elements which are being repeated inside the ng-repeat as I want to use the names of the form elements for angular validations

Comment: From what I see it can also be done using a big form, only variable name should be enough. Unless you have nested `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No, I haven't nested ng-repeat

Comment: Then any difference between identifying using `1form.1input` and `form.1input`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have other than `table` tag inside table, if you try to do that it will make your html invalid & that content will thrown out from table. here you should consider using `ng-form` inspite of `form` tag.

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="cancellationPercentData in cancellationPercent" ng-form="{{ $index}}editPercentageForm">

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Also `ng-show` don't need `{{}}`(interpolation) directive, you can form complex expression by concatenating `string` as key of `object`

```
ng-show="this.[$index+ 'editPercentageForm'][$index+'editFromHours'].$touched && 
         this.[$index+ 'editPercentageForm'][$index+'editFromHours'].$invalid"
```

Likewise correct your all other expression.

See Also
[Angular form not working in a table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34443982/2435473)

Comment: What does this represent here? Does it represent the form name?

Comment: @Harish can you provide me plunker, with what you tried?

Comment: See this is how I have written : 
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat ="x in y">
<form>
<td></td>
</form>
</tr>

But What I see in browser is different : 
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat ="x in y">
<form></form>
<td></td>

</tr>

Comment: Did you get it ?

Comment: @Harish got it, it was problem related to other tag inside `table` element

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'll make changes and let you know if it's working :)

Comment: @Harish please check linked answer as well :) Thanks :)

Comment: Working perfectly. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @Harish Glad to help you, Thanks :)